# can't acquire IDXGIDevice or IDXGIDevice1 from ID3D12Device in dx12

Tags: direct3d, dxgi, directx-12

I'd like to call IDXGIDevice1::SetMaximumFrameLatency method from my dx12app, for that I need to get a valid IDXGIDevice1 from the current Direct3D 12 device. querying the interface return a E_NOINTERFACE:

```
IDXGIDevice * pDXGIDevice;
HRESULT hr = myDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), (void **)&pDXGIDevice);
assert(hr != S_OK); // returns E_NOINTERFACE

IDXGIDevice1 * pDXGIDevice1;
HRESULT hr1 = myDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice1), (void **)&pDXGIDevice1);
assert(hr != S_OK);  // returns E_NOINTERFACE
```

Not sure if I'm missing something or there is sequence of dxgi logic I need to implement to get a valid IDXGIDevice1 interface.

Would appreciate any hints & thanks in advance!
Klip

Answer (score 2):

For Direct3D 12, this 'legacy pattern' of obtaining the DXGI factory is not supported, so your code above won't work as it's the first step:

```
    ComPtr<IDXGIDevice3> dxgiDevice;
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        m_d3dDevice.As(&dxgiDevice)
        );

    ComPtr<IDXGIAdapter> dxgiAdapter;
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        dxgiDevice->GetAdapter(&dxgiAdapter)
        );

    ComPtr<IDXGIFactory4> dxgiFactory;
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        dxgiAdapter->GetParent(IID_PPV_ARGS(&dxgiFactory))
        );
```

For Direct3D 12, you should always create the DXGI factory explicitly. See [Anatomy of Direct3D 12 Create Device](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2016/08/16/anatomy-of-direct3d-12-create-device/).

In Direct3D 12 swap chains, you explicitly control the backbuffer swapping behavior. Ideally you'd use `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_FRAME_LATENCY_WAITABLE_OBJECT` and then use the waitable object to throttle your rendering speed instead. You can set the latency count via `IDXGISwapChain2::SetMaximumFrameLatency` which defaults to 3 (MSDN is currently wrong about the defaults).

If you want to support 'higher-than-refresh-rate' updates (such as nVidia G-Sync or AMD FreeSync), then you use the new `DXGI_PRESENT_ALLOW_TEARING` flag for `Present`. For details on using this flag, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509554.aspx) or this [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wn02zCXa9IU) video.

See also [DirectX 12: Presentation Modes In Windows 10 (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3wTajGZOsA).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chuck.
I already use an explicitly created factory, 
'CreateDXGIFactory1(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory4), &dxgiFactory)'

then scan DXGI adapters to find one that supports Direct3D 12, then create the device similar to the steps described in your blog.

'D3D12CreateDevice(myAdapter, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0, __uuidof(ID3D12Device), &myDevice)'

So unless i misunderstood your reply, I'm still not sure  why i can't acquire IDXGIDevice1.
My understanding of frame latency, is that is a value that is <= than the the swap chain's buffer count to limit the driver's present queue

Comment: You can use ``IDXGISwapChain2::SetMaximumFrameLatency`` instead.

Comment: Note you can use ``IDXGISwapChain2::SetMaximumFrameLatency`` for waitable swapchains only.